# OpenGL glBufferStorage crashes

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2015, opengl-3

Whenever I call glBufferStorage(...) the subsequent glBindBuffer(..) always crashes. Ex:

```
    glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 1);
    glBufferStorage(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned int) * 100, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT | GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_READ_BIT );

    glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 2); //  <- CRASH HERE!
```

If I remove the glBufferStorage(...) call, the subsequent glBindBuffer calls dont crashes!

This code was working normally in my Desktop under a GTX650 Ti and PhenonII x6, with openGl installed via NugeT on VS2015 ( nupengl.core package ). Then I pasted the entire project folder to my Notebook ( GeForce 740M / i7 ), removed the openGl nuget package and reinstalled it.

How can I proceed to investigate what is wrong? Is this logical error or maybe gpu driver error?

Comment: Check to make sure you're using the function correctly (are all the flags correct) and make sure that it's not part of a version of OpenGL that your hardware doesn't support.

Comment: @Xirema My present hardware supports OpenGL 4.5 and the older only supported OpenGL 4.3, but the code works on the older hardware. Is this acceptable?

Comment: `glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 1);` What do you think this is doing? You're binding a number, not an actual buffer object.

Comment: @NicolBolas It was just for simplification, as you know, the genBuffer() calls returns a unsigned int as a "name" for the buffer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could make it.

As stated, I moved my project from Desktop to Laptop. My laptop have newer OpenGL support than Desktop, but my Laptop was using the CPU graphics ( Intel HD Graphics ) instead of dedicated GPU GeForce 740M.

This way, my OpenGL program was executing on a device that not supports some newer OpenGL features, like the  **GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER** target, and that's why it crashes.

Comment: You need to check for extensions before you use them. Having your app segfault instead of failing gracefully if the GPU doesn't support something will confuse users.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I had sure my code worked cause I tested it before with another ( older ) GPU, and the newer GPU is by far more capable in terms of extensions and stuff. My problem was that my SO was trying to execute the OpenGL program in the Intel HD Graphics vga, instead of dedicated GPU. I appreciate your help, thanks!